# What does 「どうであるか」mean?

Tags: grammar

[「～いかんによらず」](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=ikanniyorazu) means without regard to X.

> ～いかんによらず　＝　～いかんにかかわらず
>
> ＝　～いかんを問わず
>
> 意味　：～が**どうであるか**に関係なく

It seems like ～がどうであるかに関係なく ＝？  Without regard to whether something is probably X.

Is「どうであるか」similar to「どうであろう」or「どうだろう」? If not, how do they differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ～がどうであるかに関係なく

Means (very literally)

> Unrelated to how ～ is

I am going to assume that you have seen constructions like `〜はどうですか` or `最近どうですか`, but just in case, [どう](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%A6%82%E4%BD%95) is generally translated as "how". The above might be`How about/How is ~?` and `How have you been doing recently?`, respectively.

`～がどうであるか` is a subordinate clause literally meaning `how ～ is`. You can read more about the uses of subordinate clause questions in Japanese [here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/question.html#part3), but what is important here is that `である` is the verb for `be` and `どう` is our "how". `か` marks the whole thing as a question subordinate clause, giving us:

> (～がどうであるか) に関係なく

I am unsure where you are getting "whether something is probably X" from, but the way to express "without regard to whether something is X" would be

> ～がXかどうかに関係なく

`どうであろう` and `どうだろう` are both entirely different constructions (as is `かどうか`). The former is used to express sentiments like "however something may be", while the latter is used to emphasize uncertainty in questions asking about how something is. Explaining both in detail is beyond the scope of one question, but [here are some decent examples of どうであろう](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86&ref=sa).

Edit: [Here is the most relevant question I can find on どうだろう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40128/what-is-the-difference-between-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA-and-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86/40132#40132).

Comment: 「～がXかどうかに関係なく」Makes more sense to me. What would 「Bobは怒っているのがどうであるかに関係なく彼と相談したほがいい」mean?

Comment: I see where you got "whether or not" now. The most natural English translation will probably end up involving "whether or not" because we don't have something better. Maybe "You should consult with him regardless of whether Bob's angry or not." That said, translating really strictly, this is something like "Regardless of how Bob being angry is, you should consult with him." The Japanese doesn't actually leave room for doubt that Bob is angry, just suggests that consulting should happen anyway.